# How to get Firebase Dynamic Link URL social metadata itself

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, firebase-dynamic-links

Say I have **original URL**: [https://flutree.web.app/NWfLo\](https://flutree.web.app/NWfLo%5C)
And I shorten it using [Firebase Dynamic Link](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links), and set with Social Metadata (image, title, desc), it becomes **new URL** : https://flut.page.link/hcpa

Now I want to have a Link Preview functionality, I'm using [simple_url_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_url_preview) package. Basically, the package did a GET request of the **new URL** and parse the og(s) property from the body.

The problem is, it returns the metadata of the **original URL**, as depicted below:

[image: Url preview]

Behavior that I want to achieve is as below (Example from Telegram's Link Preview, same behavior observed on other major platform ie Twitter, WhatsApp etc):

[image: Telegram screenshot]

So, how can I get the **metadata of the Firebase Dynamic link** itself and not the original/target URL?

Comment: the long firebase dynamic link seems to contain the image description and and title,  but as far as i have researched there is no current method to fetch the full dynamic link from the short dynamic link